# SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I have some questions about SQL Server Compact Edition.

Now we are using SQL Server 2008 and developing in Visual Studio 2008 C#.net 
and linq for connect database.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to change our database to SQL Server Compact Edition?
2. What is the differece between both of this?
3. Is there any limitions when using SQL Server CE, for eg. database size, data size?
4. Can CE version support all data type from SQL Server 2008?

best regards,

Indi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of my experience using sql server compact edition.

> (1) Is it possible to change our database to sql server compact edition?

Yes

Maybe you can use this :

[Convert sql server to sql compact](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlCompactCoptUtility.aspx)

Or

[Prime works Dataport wizard](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Downloads-2.html)

> (2) What is the differece between both of this?

[Differences Between Sql server compact and sqlser server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx)

> (3) Is there any limitions to use sqlserver ce,for eg.database size,data size?

Yes, sql compact support only limited storage capacity.

[Working with SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172349%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

> (4) Can CE version supports all data type from sqlserver2008?

Not All

Regards

Comment: SQL Server CE doesn't support the data types `XML` and `VARCHAR(MAX)`, and SQL Server CE doesn't have views, triggers or stored procedures

Answer (score 3):

You can alos try my Export2SqlCe command line utility: http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com