# storing software information locally

Tags: desktop-application, local-storage

I  am designing a software application which needs to store data locally. Can you please suggest the different methods of storing data locally, I am contemplating on having mysql database or an xml file. I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of both approach. Are there any other methods other than i listed above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your stack is going to be built in. If you are in the Microsoft world, you could have a look at [SQL Server Compact Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256781/sql-server-2008-to-sql-server-compact-edition). Whether or not you need a local database or not depends on how much data you need to store, it's structure, the level of resiliency you require, the duration that the data needs to be stored for, the level of security you require etc.. I'd need more info from you to give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, The software needs to store plenty of configure options,multiple username and passwords,file and directory names,etc.The data is occasionally send to a server

Answer (score 1):

If you have too large data then SQLite is the best approach, else if there are just application settings like simple user name or password then use shared preferences. XML isnt an adopted practice when it comes to storing data.