# Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005' Could not use ''; file already in use

Tags: sql, security, asp-classic, jet

In the past few days, I've read probably any related question with the specific error. Unfortunately nothing helped.

[This](http://support.yessoftware.com/kb_article.asp?article_id=4) and [that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174943) links seems to be the same issues, but it seems that is not my problem. I'm using asp-classic and my code is:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM dbtable"

set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\dbname.mdf"
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open sql,conn
```

From all the search that I've made, it seems like I'm having some kind of security problem. So please help. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Perhaps [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can help pinpoint the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the database to a public location and update your connection string to point at the new location, ie:

```
    c:\temp\database.mdb 
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\temp\dbname.mdf"
```

See if that works first, second make sure the database is not in use currently by another process/application.

--Invalid database Type--

Use SQL Compact edition, check the following Stack Overflow answer for more information: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257062/1244017)

Comment: Now i get Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'

Unrecognized database format 'C:\path\name.mdf'.

Comment: How did you generate the MDF file?

Comment: By creating a new database in the SQL Management Studio

Comment: You can't use JET to talk to a sql server MDF database, you will need SQL express to host the database.

Comment: Make sens, my db is not hosted, it is just on my physical drive. Thanks for that!

Comment: Can you give me some advice or any web material for hosting a database on localhost

Comment: Setting up and hosting a database can be challenging the first time, but this tutorial should help you in getting started with IIS / SQL hosting. There is a lot to learn but this should set you on the right path [CodeProject - Configuring IIS/ASP.NET & SQL Express](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674930/Configuring-IIS-ASP-NET-and-SQL-Server)